# What is the name of the "Solution Explorer"-style Container control?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am coding a C# Winforms application, and I would like to create a layout that is similar to the following image:

[image]

What is the name of the control that has the TreeView inside of it? I am referring to the control that has the title text of "Solution Explorer", the minimize, pin and close buttons, and the ability to have tabs.

Rather than using a third party tool or library, how can I create my own object that is similar to the above image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about [Docking Panels](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/).

Comment: How about if I want to create my own object that is similar to the image without using a third party assembly? How should I go about this?

Comment: @user3736648 I think, it's bad idea. You'll spend a lot of time and result is not predictable :) We use Avalon Dock (https://avalondock.codeplex.com/) for WPF, and DevExpress control for WinForms

Comment: That would be a [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).  But @Backs is right...you're in for a long haul.  Don't reinvent the wheel...this sort of control has been done many times over.